# Function thinks passed variable is empty (it is not!)

Tags: php, function, variables

My PHP function thinks my variable ($type) that I am passing to it is empty, but when I tell the function to return that variable ($ype), it returns exactly what I pasted to it.

```
function getData($result, $player = 0, $type = 0){
     // This is here for me to test the bug and it prints $type ok, how when its == 0 ?
    if ($type == 0){ return $type; }
    if (!empty($result) AND $type != 0){
        return $result[$player]->$type;
    }elseif (!empty($result) AND $type == 0){
        return $result[$player];
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

This is how I call that function in the code:

```
$map_type = getData($replay, 1, "name");
```

Can there be a problem that the file with functions is included? I think nope, as other files and even functions within that file work ok.

I checked it multiple times and I do not see a typos there and I actually tested it and it worked OK.

Is there some bug with setting variables to 0 when they are not sent to function? Again, I dont think so, as the $player works and similar code works on my other functions too.

Comment: Loose comparison, `"name" == 0` but `"name" !== 0`

Comment: @MarkBaker How can a normal string equal to 0? I call shenanigans! "0" = "" = 0 = FALSE in PHP with == (not ===), but normal string? Since when?

Comment: Since forever..... that's why you have two versions of the comparison operator, one for strict comparison, one for loose comparison.... I suggest you read the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) which describes this behaviour in great detail

Comment: I know, and I use strict comparsion when really needed, but I never encountered that some string with letters in it could equal to zero. Like, I mean never.

Comment: Then take a close look at `"php"` and `0` examples in the comparison grids on the docs page that I linked above.... this is fully documented behaviour

Comment: Huh, thats weird, In all those years I never encountered such thing as string = to zero. Well, we learn every day. Could you post it as normal answer with an explanation and that link, so I can accept it? Now I feel dumb.

Comment: As a side note. I have found that using zero instead of `false` and one instead of `true` leads to several 'weird' bugs such as comparisons. If you really mean `false` then use the keyword. Its also easier to read.

Comment: @AnotherGuy I am using FALSE when I expect false, but here it was just set to 0, so I was expecting 0 or a string...

Comment: Feeling dumb is natures way of helping us learn from our mistakes.... I'm sure we've all fallen foul of this at some point or another, and felt really dumb; but feeling dumb now helps us avoid making the same mistake in the future

Comment: So true :) Thanks for help, everything works as it should now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loose-typed comparison such as `if ($type == 0){` where `$type` is a string value can lead to unexpected results.

`$type` will be [cast to a numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for the comparison according to the rules defined [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

So while a string value like `"13 Monkeys"` will be loose cast to `13`, and `"13 Monkeys" == 0` will return a `false`; but a value without any leading digits such as `"name"` will be cast to a `0`, so `"name" == 0` is `true`.

A useful page detailing all the different type comparisons (both loose and strict comparisons) can be found in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)